# how to get the next item from an javascript array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function

So, i have built and array of all the month
and i am to get the current month from it by using the getDate function
but i wanna scroll through it

```
const month = ["Januray", "Feburary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

let d = new Date();
let showMonth = month[d.getMonth()]
monthEl.textContent = showMonth
```

how to i get the next month when i click on a element with onclick="next()"
i have read other various solutions but those consists of complex arrays that i am unable to comprehend due to myself being new programming

Comment: seems like you need to specify the problem in more details and give some reproducible example

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood your Question right, where you have to scroll and where you would click? 

if you write only the next month from current month than you just set +1 behind the "month[d.getMonth()+1]".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the next month by keeping track of the index of the array. Increment the index on a call to `next()` and pull out the next month from the array using that incremented index `month[nextIndex]`;

The only gotcha is if the index grows beyond the length of the array, which will result in you getting back `undefined` instead of the month- so we have to check for this. `if (nextIndex > month.length - 1)` then set the index back to the beginning, `0` and now you have something that will loop through the array.

also you have a small typo in `Janurary` and `Feburary`.

```js
const monthEl = document.getElementById("monthEl");
let monthIndex = 0;
const month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

let d = new Date();
monthIndex = d.getMonth();
let showMonth = month[monthIndex]
monthEl.textContent = showMonth;

function next() {
  let nextIndex = ++monthIndex;
  if (nextIndex > month.length - 1) {
    nextIndex = 0;
    monthIndex = 0;
  }

  let nextMonth = month[nextIndex];
  monthEl.textContent = nextMonth;

}
```

```html
<div id="monthEl"></div>
<button onClick="next()">next</button>
```